# Move the position of the opened apps in the taskbar with the mouse or keyboard

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, taskbar

is there any desktop environment, windows manager or fork of ubuntu 12.04 that permits moving the apps in the taskbar (traditional taskbar, not unity left panel)???? You know, for example in Firefox I can change the position of the tabs. I would like to do the same for the apps in the taskbar.

I tried xfce, but it doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) allows it, and has a "traditional taskbar" like you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

Right click over the panel > Panel > Panel preferences > choose the panel > Items tab > Window buttons > click on settings button on the right > Sorting order: None, allow drag and drop.

Comment: This one should have been marked as answer. Out of the box solution. Thanks.